# Multiple values for memory resources shown when Snakemake is run

Tags: snakemake, hpc

I am running a Snakemake (V7.14.0) pipeline on the cluster and provided resources in a resource config file like:

```
threads:
    tool1: 4
mem_gb:
    tool1: 12
```

Point to it in my rules like:

```
resources:
        mem_gb=config['mem_gb']['tool1']
threads:
        config['threads']['tool1']
```

And the snakemake cluster command like:

```
snakemake --configfiles \
    config/config_resources.yml \
    config/config_parameters.yml \
    --latency-wait 60 \
    --use-conda \
    --use-singularity \
    --printshellcmds \
    --jobname MyPipe{name}_{jobid} \
    --jobs 300 \
    --cluster \
    "bsub -W 200 -n {threads} -M {resources.mem_gb}G \
    -R 'rusage[mem={resources.mem_gb}G]' \
    -o run_logs/{name}_%J.out \
    -e run_logs/{name}_%J.err"
```

What I do not understand when I run the pipeline is that it shows this in the terminal:

> threads: 4
>
> resources: mem_mb=19442, disk_mb=19442, tmpdir=/tmp, mem_gb=12

So next to the one I provided (mem_gb), there are: mem_mb, and disk_mb. They are clearly not the same value. In the cluster job it looks as though the MEMLIMIT is indeed the one I give, but the MEM usage is different (higher). Is it because Snakemake does not understand the mem_gb and I specifically need to use that word?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined `mem_gb` but not `mem_mb` in your resource configuration file. You can set them to same value by adding something like `mem_mb=config['mem_gb']['tool1']`. Additional information in their [documentation](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/executing/cli.html#profiles).

Comment: Thanks for the response. So basically, Snakemake does not understand mem_gb. So to do this correctly, I need to actually *1000 the values. Because otherwise I get too low values (e.g. 6 mb instead of 6 gb).